# When i run docker-compose on windows 11, i've an error 'docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.', despite that docker-compose is installed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, git-bash, windows-11

i installed docker desktop on windows 11, following instruction here : [docs.docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/). I can run `docker`command but when i run `docker-compose` or `docker compose` i got the following error :

```bash
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
```

I can see the executables are installed correctly when i type :

```bash
where docker compose
// C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose
   C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe
```

```bash
where docker
// C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker
   C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe
```

I'm using git bash on Windows 11.

I'm expecting to read a `docker-compose.yml` file on a project by running `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Why git bash? Use the regular windows terminal.

Comment: add how you solved it in an answer

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit to the question -- instead of editing a question to include the answer (which can get confusing for future users), it's better to add the solution as an answer (as you've already done!)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! (it was my first question on stackoverflow, sorry for my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall docker, then i restarted the computer and installed it again. And this time, instead of skipping the tutorial (quick start guide), i did it and everything worked fine.

Comment: Why do you think that worked? Was the PATH environment variables updated?

Comment: I could not say, I'm a still learning and docker is still very new to me. Sorry

Comment: That is OK. I am just thinking a bit more detail would make an answer more useful to future readers.

Comment: I think it's because I skipped the quick start guide, and I believe it's mandatory for the initialization of docker desktop.